# Make 'CTRL-/' behave the same in vtty and xterm

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts, console, tty, xterm

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> in a graphical terminal (e.g. xterm) I get "undo".  However, in a virtual terminal (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) I get "backspace".

In practice I run into this when I'm using emacs in a virtual terminal, probably debugging some X problem, and I try to use <kbd>C</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to undo but instead get a backspace.

I believe I have experienced this on multiple computers over the years, so I don't think it's very specific to my current setup (ubuntu).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you press a key in xterm, it sends a character sequence that is determined by the translations in its [X resources](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_resources). Typically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> sends the single character `^_` (i.e. character number 31, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd>). The shell interprets this control character as the undo command.

When you press the key in a Linux console, it sends a character sequence that is determined by the active keymap. The command [`loadkeys`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/loadkeys) loads a keymap. The location of the default keymap depends on the distribution and on the installed packages; on recent Ubuntu distributions, the console keymap is derived from the default XKB keymap. Many default keymap assign Backspace (which is called `Delete` in this context: it's character 127) to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> (I don't know why); you can change this by using the following keymap fragment:

```
keycode  53 = slash            question        
        control keycode  53 = Control_underscore
        alt     keycode  53 = Meta_slash      
        shift   alt     keycode  53 = Meta_question
```

If you have a file called `/etc/console/boottime.kmap.gz`, edit that. If you have a file `/etc/default/keyboard`, read it and follow the instructions.

Comment: Thanks! I have `/etc/default/keyboard`. I'm using `XKBOPTIONS` there, and I don't want to maintain a full separate keymap, so I'm looking for a more modular solution.  Loading the keymap fragment you give above with `sudo loadkeys <file with keymap fragment>` works for the current session, and I guess I could run that from an `init.d` script.

Comment: @enoksrd Right, you can use an `init.d` script, or even add `loadkeys </etc/enoksrd/custom.kmap` to `/etc/rc.local`.