# How to make xterm recognize control-slash?

Tags: keyboard, escape-characters, xterm

When I'm using an xterm, the keyboard sequence Ctrl+/ produces Ctrl-_.  Here is the result of `showkey -a` when first hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, then hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>. I am on a US ANSI keyboard.

```
[ ~ ] showkey -a

Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program

^_       31 0037 0x1f
^_       31 0037 0x1f
```

I want to actually get `^/` (or whatever it would look like) because I have a customized binding associated with C-/ in Emacs, which works fine if I start an Emacs GUI, but not at all when I run `emacs -nw` because it just receives the C-_ (which does 'undo').

I don't need to mess with xmodmap (actual key *mappings* are okay).  I've looked into vt100 translations, e.g. I have the following already (from documentation [here](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R6.7.0/doc/xterm.1.html), among others):

```
XTerm*VT100.translations: #override \n\
    <Key> Prior: scroll-back(1, halfpage) \n\
    <Key> Next: scroll-forw(1, halfpage)
```

But can I use translations to just get a different key rather than run a command? I've tried adding a line with `Ctrl <Key> /:` using `insert()` just to override, which didn't work. I've tried using `string("0xffe4") string("0x2f")`, and that gives me the slash but the attempt to put in the Ctrl failed with weirdness ... I got the keysym for Ctrl_R from looking at `xev`, but I'm not sure that's the right thing to use.

I've also looked at `modifyOtherKeys` and its documentation [here](https://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/xterm.html#VT100-Widget-Resources:modifyOtherKeys), but setting it to 1 didn't help and setting it to 2 broke pretty much everything.

**What is intercepting C-/ and turning it into C-_, and can I overcome it?**

*Critical note:* I am not root nor have any superuser privileges on the system(s) in question. Stuff in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43429/make-ctrl-behave-the-same-in-vtty-and-xterm) looked relevant, but any call of `loadkeys` gives me an error to do with permissions.

Comment: The question's partly relevant, but other related answers point out that in a *terminal*, the control modifier usually acts as a mask (AND'ing with 0x1f), so control-/ and control-_ map to the same character.  GUIs use different rules.

Comment: There's no such thing as a `^/` character

Comment: @ThomasDickey Um, I did get that yes GUIs use different rules.  Is the 'ANDing with 0x1f' documented anywhere for xterm?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Okay ... but say I do set modifyOtherKeys to 2 then I definitely get different results from Ctrl+Shift+- and Ctrl+/.  Is setting that to 2 (which causes very drastic things to happen) the *only* way to peel apart Ctrl-/ and Ctrl-_?

Comment: @Ajean, you can always use translations to get xterm to send whatever sequence of characters you want upon Ctrl+/, and then bind that in emacs.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Is there a way to send Ctrl again or am I limited to strings? That might be the overall answer, I just haven't found very good (any) documentation for the syntax of that translations resource.

Comment: Applications in terminals read bytes values from the /dev/pts/x device as sent there by the terminal emulator (from the master side of the pseudo-tty pair). Ctrl+_ sends the `^_` (aka US in ASCII) character, the 0x1f byte. There's no `^/`, but you can send a sequence of characters starting with the ESC character (aka, `^[`, `\e`, 0x1b) like the one sent upon Ctrl+/ woth modifyOtherKeys

Comment: So something like `^[[27;5;47~`? (That's what shows up in showkey for Ctrl / when modifyOtherKeys is 2)  I'll give that a shot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Stéphane Chazelas I was able to do the following and solve the issue - I put `Ctrl <Key> /: string("0x1b") string("/")` into my vt100.translations resource, like so:

```
XTerm*VT100.translations: #override \n\
    <Key> Prior: scroll-back(1, halfpage) \n\
    <Key> Next: scroll-forw(1, halfpage) \n\
    Ctrl <Key> /: string("0x1b") string("/")
```

which makes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> transmit 'ESC-/' (it was using escape, and escape being 0x1b, or 27, that I was really missing). Then I was able to add another binding in Emacs to handle that just like my current C-/ binding. That way I am now able to hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> on the keyboard and have Emacs receive M-/ (Emacs notation)<sup>1</sup> so that it behaves the same in GUI and terminal.

---

<sup>1</sup> Emacs has a default binding on M-/ already to 'dabbrev-expand'. Since I never use that, I had no qualms overriding it.